# Terminal, vim and ssh color problem

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, display, colors

I'm using vim for my editor. I've problems about the colors of vim. The same colorscheme of vim gives different outputs in terminal, ssh session and screen. I learnt they've different colors(16, 88 or 256).

I don't care of using 16 color or 256 color. Also the terminal emulator is not very important to me. My questions:

1- How do I use same vim colorscheme with same output on everywhere?
2- I want to write a color definition and use it every terminal(maybe with Xdefaults file). Is it possible?

Comment: Does setting your TERM env variable yield more consistent results?

Comment: should I export TERM to use same colors? I'll try it.

Comment: @Jeff setting TERM to xterm-256color and using a terminal emulator which supports 256color solved the color differentiation problem :)

Answer (score 1):

`vim`, `screen` and `ssh` all inherit the color limitations of your terminal.

If your terminal only supports 8 or 16 (like Terminal.app on Mac OS X) colors almost all the cool vim color schemes will be horrible no matter how you launch vim. If your terminal supports 256 colors you'll have to make sure Vim actually knows that your terminal is actually able to output 256 colors.

See `:help xterm-colors` for detailed info.